# How do I use an ASP.Net MVC layout page whose code is stored in the database, rather than in a file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the HTML for a layout page stored in my database rather than in a static file. How can I use this as a layout page to display content in my application?

For example, I'd tried this approach where I could have this static layout page whose body tag looks like this:

```
<body>
    @Html.Action("GetBody", "Layout")
</body>
```

GetBody could call a controller action to get my page from the database (but in this example just returning text for simplicity):

```
public ActionResult GetBody()
{
        return Content("<div>here's my content: <br /> @RenderBody()</div>", "text/html");
}
```

Part of this text would include @RenderBody(), but this renders as text rather than it being the call to the RenderBody method. I appreciate this is the expected behaviour as it's just text, but is there a way to actually render the body here in this way?

Comment: @mason thanks, I have rephrased the question.

Comment: If you start a new visual studio MVC project, all the needed files are there.

Comment: @mason I've rewritten the question for clarity please consider re-opening it

Comment: I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @VDWWD I don't think the question was clear enough as the needed files might have been there but it's the approach I'm not sure of. Please see edited question.

Comment: Is the purpose of this to have a way to update the MVC site without having to restart the web server?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the primary reason is to allow a user to design their own layout page (they can already create content pages in the app itself) which is stored in the database - we don't necessarily have access to write to the filesystem.
But yes a useful side-effect is that the server wont have to be restarted

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or .NET Standard?

Comment: @RobertHarvey .Net Standard

Comment: You mean .NET Framework? So, the old ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: @mason yes that's right

Comment: So I don't really have time to research this right now, but if I were doing this today I would find the source code for Html.Render, study it, and write my own custom one that talks to the database.  It might only require minor modifications to the original source code.  There's some precedent for this already; [custom HTML helper methods are a thing.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)